# Discord.py on_message causing loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I have encountered a problem while making a bot in discord.py, I managed to get the commands and `on_message` to work alongside each other, with quite a bit of difficulty, but now all the commands work but if i trigger one of the `on_message` functions, it loops the output for no clear reason. I am unsure on how to fix this issue, nor identify it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
import time
import typing

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')

with open("words.txt") as file:
    words = [word.strip().lower() for word in file.readlines()]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_content = message.content.strip().lower()
    for word in words:
        if word in message_content:
            await message.channel.send(f"<CUSTOMSERVEREMOJI>")
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on_message(message)` function should include 2 items to work smoothly.

1. At the beginning skip messages from the bot itself - with something like the following:

```py
if message.author == bot.user:
    return
```

2. At the end process commands (since a command is processed by `on_message` first) - with something like

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```